# How to permanently store a ResourceFunction when PersistResourceFunction and PacletizeResourceFunction don't work?

Tags: resourcefunction

I would like to permanently store some resource functions. I would like to store SetPartitions. I used [PacletizeResourceFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PacletizeResourceFunction) created by Lukas Lang to store this function.
However, it's not working.

[image]
Lukas Lang notes,

> Some pacletized resource functions might not work as expected if they
> rely on precise details of the ResourceFunction loading and evaluation
> mechanism.

I would also like to store [BirdSay](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BirdSay), but its not working.

[image]

How can I store ResourceFunctions that PacletizeResourceFunction cannot pacletize correctly?

I discuss this issue at a [Wolfram Community Post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2938626).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround with InitializationValue and Initialize.
This stores the input, say BirdSay, as BirdSayResourceFunction, to avoid conflicts with BirdSay from PacletizeResourceFunction.

```wl
ClearAll[InitializeResourceFunction]; 
SetAttributes[InitializeResourceFunction, {Listable}]; 
InitializeResourceFunction[input_] := 
 CompoundExpression[
  Evaluate[
   InitializationValue[Evaluate[input <> "ResourceFunction"], 
     "Local"] = ResourceFunction[input][##] &], 
  Initialize[
   Evaluate[ToExpression@Evaluate[input <> "ResourceFunction"]]]]
```

To use it, you can do something like

```wl
InitializeResourceFunction["BirdSay"]
```

or

```
InitializeResourceFunction["SetPartitions"]
```

Then do something like

```wl
SetPartitionsResourceFunction[{8, 1}]
```

or

```wl
BirdSayResourceFunction["I'm a bird."]
```

[image]

The function can be stored in the cloud with

```wl
CloudSave[InitializeResourceFunction, "InitializeResourceFunction"]
```

To get the function, do

```wl
CloudGet["InitializeResourceFunction"]
```